# Copy To Command in Postgres, is this possible?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to see if via Postgres I can get the Top command to return back to my client.

This does run, but it only returns '1 row affected in 278 ms'   Is there anyway to get the results from the TOP command?

```
copy
  (Select '')
to program
  'top -b -n 1'
with (
  format text);
```

I tried this in many different ways, tried Googling and looked at the copy command documenation.  This seems like it could be possible but I can't figured out a way to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a temporary table with a single column and then do `copy <table> from program . . . `

Comment: Sounds like you want to `copy from program`, not `copy to program`

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently doing is sending data *to* the program.  Then the output of the program gets captured by the server log file, but doesn't get sent to the client.

You can do what you want, but not in a single step.  You can store the program output in a table, then read from the table:

```
create temp table  t (t text);
copy t from program 'top -b -n 1' with (format text);
copy t to stdout;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton jjanes.  Although I was getting a driver error on the "copy t to stdout".

But this worked.

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
create temp table  t (t text);
copy t from program 'top -b -n 1' with (format text);
Select * from t;